# Вывести сам перевод из двоичной системы в десятичную в c++

Tags: c++, строки, циклы, while

Например, при вводе 1011 нужно вывести строку "2^0 + 2^1 + 2^3"
Ещё нужно обязательно использовать do while

```
int temp;
cin >> temp;
int base = 1;
int k = -1;
int n = 0;
while (temp) {
    int last = temp % 10;
    temp = temp / 10;
    decVal += last * base;
    base = base * 2;
    k += 1;
    cout << '2^', k;
}
```

Comment: а в чем именно у вас сложности?

Comment: не понимаю как с помощью цикла выводить всё время строки

Comment: какие строки? с помощью цикла вы пройдете по всем буквам строки, переведете буквы в цифры и вычислите (через накопление) значение числа

Comment: не очень понимаю..  вот мой код но он не выводит 2 в степени int decVal = 0;
    int base = 1;
    int temp = bin;
    int k = -1;
    int n = 0;
    while (temp) {
        int last = temp % 10;
        temp = temp / 10;
        decVal += last * base;
        base = base * 2;
        k += 1;
        cout << '2^', k;
    }

Comment: вы бы код в основной вопрос разместили - так удобнее
и еще непонятно что подается на вход - число в десятеричной системе или строка с числом в двоичной системе? и на выходе вам надо получить число или строку? Вы бы переформулировали вопрос на более точный. Потому что по присланному коду вам нужно что=то совсем другое :)

Comment: на вход число в двоичной. на выходе надо строку "2^0 + 2^1 + 2^3"

Comment: а как передается число в двоичном виде? как строка?

Comment: нет как интеджер?

Comment: т.е. вы передаете число `const val = 10` и это должно означать 2?, т.е. `1*2^1 + 0*2^0`?

Comment: да. только если умножение на ноль выводить не надо

Comment: тогда для удобства - в режиме правки добавьте свой код в свой основной вопрос и тогда можно будет более конкретно указать на ошибки и варианты их решения

Comment: готово! но нужно ещё использовать do while

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение вашей задачи, тут все просто, комментарии я написал, чтоб вы смогли разобраться

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int temp;
    cin >> temp; // Ввели число
    int power = 0; // Текущая степень
    do {
        if (temp % 10 == 1) { // Если последняя цифра = 1
            cout << "2^" << power; // то выводим на экран 2^(текущая степень)
            if (temp / 10 > 0) cout << " + "; // Если это не последняя единица, то выводим "+"
        }
        power++; // Увеличиваем степень не зависимо от условия
        temp /= 10; // Переходим к следующей цифре
    } while (temp > 0); // Выполнять пока число не стало 0
}
```